# Can you get Google Forms to keep the answer images in a generated response document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to build a questionnaire form and we have a question that clients will answer by selecting an image.  When the response is submitted, I have it set up to save the response in a Google Sheet, and then save a Google Doc with that information.  I know we can see the images selected in individual responses, but since this will go out to every client who requests our services on a project, I would like it to place the selected inspiration images in the Google Doc template.  I'm not sure if there's any way to do this, since it just exports the text value.  I have used a basic Google Apps Script to output to the document from Google Sheets, but since the response doesn't place the image into Google Sheets, it will only place the text value associated with the image into the Google Doc.  Does anyone know a way to have an image placed, corresponding to the text selected?  Would getResponseForItem(item) work to pull the image?

```
function newLeadAutoFill(e) {
  var timestamp = e.values[0];
  var firstName = e.values[1];
  var lastName = e.values[2];
  var address = e.values[3];
  var phone = e.values[4];
  var email = e.values[5]
  var budget = e.values[6];
  var hardscapes = e.values[7];
  var landscapes = e.values[8];
  var shape = e.values[9];
  var material = e.values[10];
  var other = e.values[11];
  var notes = e.values[12];
  var design = e.values[16];

  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById("doctemplate");
  var templateResponseFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("savelocation");

  var copy = templateFile.makeCopy(lastName +', ' + firstName + '-' + timestamp, templateResponseFolder);
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());

  var body = doc.getBody();

  body.replaceText("{{FirstName}}",firstName);
  body.replaceText("{{LastName}}",lastName);
  body.replaceText("{{Address}}",address);
  body.replaceText("{{Phone}}",phone);
  body.replaceText("{{Email}}",email);
  body.replaceText("{{Budget}}",budget);
  body.replaceText("{{Hardscapes}}",hardscapes);
  body.replaceText("{{Landscape}}",landscapes);
  body.replaceText("{{Shape}}",shape);
  body.replaceText("{{Material}}",material);
  body.replaceText("{{Other}}",other);
  body.replaceText("{{ClientNotes}}",notes);
  body.replaceText("{{Design}}",design);
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

I need the options shown below to be placed in a Google Doc in the {{Design}} placeholder with the images associated with each option.  **Note:** Images in the form are not the final images and are being used only for testing purposes.
[Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jwf5.jpg)  [User input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEkLX.jpg)   [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l97xL.jpg)

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: I have a question on my form that is checkboxes with attached images.  When a potential client selects an image that they like for a style, I would like to be able to generate a document with their input from the entire form, including the images attached.  Currently the document generated includes only the text input and I would like to get the images I have attached as well.  I will see if I can edit and add an image

Comment: Thank you for replying and providing more information. In your added 2 images, which is the sample input situation or the sample output situation you expect?

Comment: In the form with images, the user will select the image or images that most closely resembles their desired style.  On submit it will output a Google Doc with the choices the user selects.  However, when I output the Google Doc, it places the text "Option 1, Option 2, Option 3" into the placeholder {{Design}}, and I am trying to find a way to include the image that goes along with each option.

Comment: That's okay.  No need for apology.  English can be difficult and knowing any language outside of your native language is hard.  I will try to find a way that it is easier to understand.

Comment: I have added new images that may help you understand better.  The "template" link is the Google Doc template file that I am using for the output, the "User Input" link is the Google Form selection that I have built with images, and the "Result" link is the current output of my code.  I am currently using a Google Sheet file to store the form results, and then they are being placed into the Google Doc template by my code.  I am trying to learn how to place the images along with the text that is ending up in the result file.  Thank you for continuing to try to help me with this.